# Start a simple DerbyJS project on Cloud9

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide, derbyjs

I am trying to deploy a simple derby project on Cloud9.

I have created a workspace using Node.js and added the content of following 4 files.

index.html:

```
<Body:>
  <!--Templates define both HTML and model-view bindings-->
  Holler: <input value="{{hello.message}}">
  <h2>{{hello.message}}</h2>
```

index.js:

```
var app = module.exports = require('derby').createApp('hello', __filename);
app.loadViews(__dirname);

// Routes render on client as well as server
app.get('/', function(page, model) {
  // Subscribe specifies the data to sync
  model.subscribe('hello.message', function() {
    page.render();
  });
});
```

server.js:

```
require('derby-starter').run(__dirname, {port: process.env.PORT});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "derby-examples",
  "description": "Example applications for the Derby framework",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "repository": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "derby": "0.6.0-alpha41",
    "derby-starter": "^0.2.6",
    "derby-stylus": "~0.1.0",
    "express": "~3.18.0",
    "d-connection-alert": "~0.1.0",
    "d-before-unload": "~0.1.0",
    "d-bootstrap": "~0.1.0",
    "d-codemirror": "~0.2.0",
    "d-showdown": "~0.1.0",
    "derby-debug": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  }
}
```

When I start the server, it keeps saying

```
Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!                                                                                             

debugger listening on port 15454                                                                                                                                                        
Master pid  27985                                                                                                                                                                       
debugger listening on port 15454                                                                                                                                                        
Failed to open socket on port 15454, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
```

and continues with

```
Failed to open socket on port 15454, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
```

How can I start the server properly?

Answer (score 0):

This error is from the debugger, can you turn it off and try again? You can turn off the debugger by clicking on the green bug icon on the run panel.